# Accessing a shared mailbox using redemption, for a Vb.net outlook add in

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I m working on a outlook add in using Redemption, which has to move emails from my outlook inbox to a specified folder.
It works fine until it is for the local mailbox.
When i try to do the same on a shared mailbox,from my outlook it doesn't work.
Meaning on my outlook i access the shared mailbox and try to move the mail from shared mailboxes "Inbox" to a folder in shared mailbox itself.

I use the below code for the same.

```
oTempFolder = oRDOSession.GetSharedMailbox("mailbox name")
```

It throws the below error:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Redemption.RDOStoreClass' to interface type 'Redemption.RDOFolder'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{15B8597F-0A55-4361-AE8B-1F690BC61EE4}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I tried putting the mailbox name and the mailbox address also, nothing helped.

I tried the below code, found here on stackoverflow itself

```
store = _session.Stores.GetSharedMailbox("Example shared mailbox ");
```

But it didn't make a difference.

Can someone please guide me into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of Research and trial i found a solution to the above question.
Below code line is actual beginning of it.

```
store = _session.Stores.GetSharedMailbox("Example shared mailbox ");
```

Below is the code to find the folder in the shared mailbox you need to find.

```
 Dim Rclass As Redemption.RDOStore
 Dim oTempFolders As Redemption.RDOFolders    
 Dim oTempFolder As Redemption.RDOFolder          
 Rclass = oRDOSession.Stores.GetSharedMailbox(aFolders(0))

 oTempFolders = Rclass.IPMRootFolder.Folders

 For i = 1 To oTempFolders.Count

   oTempFolder2 = oTempFolders.Item(i)

   If oTempFolder2.Name.ToLower = "folder name" Then
       oTempFolder = oTempFolder2
       Exit For
   End If
 Next
```

Hope this helps someone who comes accross this issue.